# No Zoom on Dynamic Fixed Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic navigation which follows the user down the page. On mobile, I do not want the navigation to zoom in, as you will not be able to access the navigation on the right.

The method I tried broke the entire navigation. Any other ideas?

Live navigation at http://beeskneesfx.com/

**The Two Containers in Question Are** `#top-bar` & `#top-bar-fixed`

**Controller JS** *The commented out code is what I tried*

```
/* FLOAT NAV CONTROLLER */

$(function(){

    var bar = $('#top-bar'),
        showBar = true,
        stalkbutton = $('#stalkbutton'),
        state = false;

    if ( notMobile == false ) {
        showBar = false;
    }


    floatNav();


    $(window).scroll(function () {

        floatNav();

    });

    function floatNav() {

        $('.close-float').click(function () {
            if (state == true) {
                state = false;
                showBar = false;
                bar.slideUp(200, function () {
                    $(this).attr('id', 'top-bar').css('display', 'block');
                });
            }
        });

        if (showBar && state == false && $(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            bar.attr('id', 'top-bar-fixed').slideDown('slow', function () {
                state = true;
                /*$(this).css({transform: 'scale(' + window.innerWidth/document.documentElement.clientWidth + ')',
                            left: window.pageXOffset + 'px',
                            bottom: document.documentElement.clientHeight - (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) + 'px'});*/
            });
        } else if (state == true && $(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
            state = false;
            bar.slideUp(200, function () {
                $(this).attr('id', 'top-bar').css('display', 'block');
            });
        }
    }

});
```

**The CSS**

```
.logo { 
        float: left;
        color: #30546b;
        line-height: 49px;
}

.logo img {
        position: relative;
    float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
}

.logo .bloom {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
}

.main-width-nav {
        width: 75%;
    min-width: 1005px;
        max-width: 1428px;
        height: 45px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
}

#homebutton {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity:0.75;
    top: 50%;
    left: 295px;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);

}

#stalkbutton {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    opacity:0.75;
    top: 50%;
    left: 310px;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#top-bar .close-float {
    display:none;
}

#top-bar-fixed .main-width-nav .close-float {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 45px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#top-bar, #bottom-bar {
        background: url(http://gfxgaming.cu.cc/images/gamurs/pattern-bg-menu.png) repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        padding: 6px 0 5px;
} 

#top-bar-spacer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
    background: #131313;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #131313 0%, #1c1c1c 9%, #111111 28%, #000000 49%, #2b2b2b 81%, #2c2c2c 93%, #4c4c4c 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #131313), color-stop(9%, #1c1c1c), color-stop(28%, #111111), color-stop(49%, #000000), color-stop(81%, #2b2b2b), color-stop(93%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(100%, #4c4c4c));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #131313 0%, #1c1c1c 9%, #111111 28%, #000000 49%, #2b2b2b 81%, #2c2c2c 93%, #4c4c4c 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #131313 0%, #1c1c1c 9%, #111111 28%, #000000 49%, #2b2b2b 81%, #2c2c2c 93%, #4c4c4c 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #131313 0%, #1c1c1c 9%, #111111 28%, #000000 49%, #2b2b2b 81%, #2c2c2c 93%, #4c4c4c 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #131313 0%, #1c1c1c 9%, #111111 28%, #000000 49%, #2b2b2b 81%, #2c2c2c 93%, #4c4c4c 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#131313', endColorstr='#4c4c4c', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}

#top-bar {
        background: #242b35; /* Old browsers */background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%, #242b35 50%, #181f29 51%, #181f29 98%,         #75196a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#242b35), color-stop(50%,#242b35), color-stop(51%,#181f29), color-stop(98%,#181f29), color-stop(100%,#75196a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#242b35', endColorstr='#75196a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4B1B4C;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
}

#top-bar-fixed {
        display: none;
        background: #242b35; /* Old browsers */background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%, #242b35 50%, #181f29 51%, #181f29 98%,         #75196a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#242b35), color-stop(50%,#242b35), color-stop(51%,#181f29), color-stop(98%,#181f29), color-stop(100%,#75196a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #242b35 0%,#242b35 50%,#181f29 51%,#181f29 98%,#75196a 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#242b35', endColorstr='#75196a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        border-bottom: 2px solid #001727;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 8px 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4B1B4C;
        padding: 7px 0 4px 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
}


#top-bar-fix {
        height: 70px;
    background: rgba(85,191,255,0.5);
}
```

Comment: So you are not wanting the user to be able to zoom? You can turn off the ability with the viewport tag.

Comment: I want them to be able to zoom, but I would like the fixed version of the bar to be within the scope of the view-port at all times. Basically, when they zoom in, the navigation gets pushed off screen making it un-usable. I'd like it to remain at a 'valid' zoom level so that it all shows. Valid being whatever dimension keeps all elements in-line, and on-scren.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by changing the following css rules:

```
.main-width-nav {
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 1005px; // this is what is breaking your layout
    max-width: 1428px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

to:

```
.main-width-nav {
    width: 100%; // gave it 100% to give it more room to move around
    min-width: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That is what keeps the navigation centered with the rest of the layout. It's not suppose to be 100% width of the screen, but within the 75% width of the whole layout.

Comment: well you can certainly keep the 75% width rule. The issue was with your min-width rule

Comment: Is there a reason? I wanted to make sure the layout would not be under a 1024x786 display, otherwise everything would be broken and not have room. I don't see the reasoning, or what it has to do with the zoom aspect of mobile devices.

Comment: The reason is that you cannot guarantee that the screen viewing your page has a width of 1005px. This is especially apparent when zooming. When this occurs all of your content is going to be forced off the right side of the screen and any `position:abolute;` or `position:fixed` elements will not be fully visible if this rule is applied to them

Comment: At that point, the width the body would be changed allowing for scrolling to the right though. Which is the point of keeping the nav from zooming AT ALL to keep it within the frame, whatever width it may be... The question also pertains to keeping that element from zooming. THe code I used caused everything to break, lost the background BG element for the nav, all sorts of weird stuff.

Comment: Here is an article that addressed the issue. As he points out, there are too many edge cases for a javascript solution to be feasible:

http://dbushell.com/2013/09/10/css-fixed-positioning-and-mobile-zoom/

Comment: I have read this. I have also seen working examples online, just don't have access to their JS. And their containers came complete with about 20 divs for their gradient and shadow effects. Is there not a way to set the master container and all sub content to follow that rule?

Comment: Not for `position:fixed` elements. Position:fixed takes the element out of the normal document flow so the element is no longer effected by the positioning or size of it's parent.

Comment: For, the fixed element; IE: `#top-bar-fixed` Not it's parent.